# Array order in `numpy.dot`

Tags: python, numpy

In Python's [numerical library NumPy](http://numpy.org/), how does the `numpy.dot` function deal with arrays of different memory-order? `numpy.dot(c-order, f-order)` vs. `dot(f-order, c-order)` etc.

The reason I ask is that long time ago (numpy 1.0.4?), I made some tests and noticed `numpy.dot` performed worse than calling `dgemm` from `scipy.linalg` directly, with the correct transposition flags, though both call the same BLAS library internally. (I suspected the reason was copying of the input matrices inside `numpy.dot`, which is tragic if the input is large.)

Now I tried again and actually `numpy.dot` performs the same as `dgemm`, so there is no reason to keep the arrays in specific order and set transposition flags manually. Much cleaner code.

So my question is, how does a recent (let's say 1.6.0) `numpy.dot` work, guarantees on when things are copied and when not? I'm concerned about 1) memory 2) performance here. Cheers.

Comment: Questions about specific packages may be more likely to get an answer on the relevant mailing list.

Comment: Ok, I'll copy&paste there as well. The right-hand panel is filled with numpy questions though, I see there are over 1,000 of them here on SO already :)

Comment: There's no shortage of them, it's just that the mailing list will get you a much more specialized audience (i.e. the developers). For a question like this that focuses on the internals of a package, you're much more likely to get a good answer on the mailing list than you are on SO. Of course, asking on both doesn't hurt! (Which, incidentally, it appears that you did... Hopefully you'll get a clear answer there!)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly what you were seeing may have been related to a blas-optimized dot import error being caught and handled silently  (this code snippet is from numeric.py)

```
# try to import blas optimized dot if available
try:
    # importing this changes the dot function for basic 4 types
    # to blas-optimized versions.
    from _dotblas import dot, vdot, inner, alterdot, restoredot
except ImportError:
    # docstrings are in add_newdocs.py
    inner = multiarray.inner
    dot = multiarray.dot
```

Comment: `blah.T` changes shape of the array, so replacing `blah` with `blah.T` won't work unless the proper gemm `transpose` flag is set at the same time.

Anyhow, it seems noone really knows what happens inside numpy.dot. Perhaps the copies are made inside BLAS and numpy has nothing to do with -- just the linked BLAS itself improved, making smarter decisions about when to make temporary copies.

That would mean I better keep taking care of array order myself, as the memory overhead is BLAS-dependent and unpredictable across installations.